# Voip(incoming call) notification did not receive when app kill or terminated in flutter (ios)

Tags: ios, flutter, voip

When my App is not running and receives a Push Notification but app didn't show incoming call in ios,

The call Notifications do work perfectly when the App is running - either as the Active app or while in the background - but nothing works correctly when the app is not running (Killed) only in ios.

Anybody have any ideas how to make incoming call from Push Notifications when they arrive while the App was NOT running in ios ?

i thought i show call screen from below function but when app is killed this function can't run in ios so I did't receive incoming call, If anyone do this help me to figure this issue

Thank you

`    @pragma('vm:entry-point')

```
Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  print("Handling a background message: ${message.data}");

  Map<String, dynamic> str = message.data;
  if (str['type'] == 'Calling you') {
    showCallkitIncoming(const Uuid().v4(), str);
  }
}  `





    func pushRegistry(_ registry: PKPushRegistry, didReceiveIncomingPushWith payload: PKPushPayload, for type: PKPushType, completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
        print("didReceiveIncomingPushWith")
//        guard type == .voIP else { return } 
        
        let id = payload.dictionaryPayload["id"] as? String ?? ""
        let nameCaller = payload.dictionaryPayload["nameCaller"] as? String ?? ""
        let handle = payload.dictionaryPayload["handle"] as? String ?? ""
        let isVideo = payload.dictionaryPayload["isVideo"] as? Bool ?? false
        
        let data = flutter_callkit_incoming.Data(id: id, nameCaller: nameCaller, handle: handle, type: isVideo ? 1 : 0)
        //set more data
        data.extra = ["user": "abc@123", "platform": "ios"]
        //data.iconName = ...
        //data.....
        SwiftFlutterCallkitIncomingPlugin.sharedInstance?.showCallkitIncoming(data, fromPushKit: true)
        
        //Make sure call completion()
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.5) {
            completion()
        }
    }
```

in this case some time call create and some time call not created in app is terminated

Comment: You need to make sure you are sending a [voip](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/pushkit/responding_to_voip_notifications_from_pushkit) push